# Which's the right waypoint direction?

Tags: jquery-waypoints

The waypoint direction should be recognized like the left or the right?

[image]

Actually, I have tested. And I got to the id mark by the `a` tag. However, the two results all appeared.

So confused, thanks for your answer.

/****************** UPDATE ********************/

I made a new test just now, [here is my test](https://jsfiddle.net/daxiao/suf4c9ud/).

However, the results all came to be the right one (in the img above).

I will try to reappear my problem, thankyou.

Comment: You should show the code that you used for the test and explain in more details what you don't understand and what result do you want to get. As currently written, it's not clear what you're asking (well, for me at least)

Comment: Some code would help